# Updating rows with values from another table in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have two tables, one with data about counties and another with data about states. Different states can sometimes have counties with the same exact name, so I am trying to populate a `unique_name` column in my counties table that is the concatenation of a county name and the abbreviation of the state where that county is located (e.g.: Honolulu County, HI).

I have come up with the following query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE counties
    UPDATE unique_name =
    (
        SELECT concat(counties.name, ', ', states.name_abbr)
        FROM counties
        INNER JOIN states
        ON counties.statefp = states.statefp
    ) WHERE unique_name = ''
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
DB::Exception: Unknown identifier: states.statefp, context: required_names: 'states.statefp' source_tables: table_aliases: private_aliases: column_aliases: public_columns: masked_columns: array_join_columns: source_columns: .
```

The inner query is working perfectly fine on its own, but I don't why this error is coming up when I try to do the update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

ClickHouse does not support dependent joins for ALTER TABLE UPDATE. Fortunately, there is a workaround. You have to create a special Join engine table for the update. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE states_join as states Engine = Join(ANY, LEFT, statefp);

INSERT INTO states_join SELECT * from states;

ALTER TABLE counties 
UPDATE unique_name = concat(name, joinGet('states_join', 'name_abbr', statefp))
WHERE unique_name = '';

DROP TABLE states_join;
```

Note, it only works in 19.x versions.

Comment: The concat part works as expected (tested by `select concat(name, joinGet('states_join', 'name_abbr', statefp)) from counties`). However, the update statement does not actually update any rows in the `unique_name` column.

Comment: Could you check your system.mutations table? Any error here?

Comment: @MarcioPorto maybe you're trying to update the column which is a part of ORDER BY key?

Comment: hi @AlexanderZaitsev; I'm getting a similar behavior. The systems.mutations table has the following error: Code: 125. DB::Exception: Scalar subquery returned more than one row. Any hints?