# How can I add column from one table to another in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table having following columns: **(id, col1,col2)**. I need to add **col3** from a temporary table having **(id,col3)**. So that after the operation table 1 should be: **(id,col1,col2,col3)** . After this, I drop the temporary table. How can this be done in Clickhouse?

I know of an [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764093/updating-rows-with-values-from-another-table-in-clickhouse#:%7E:text=ClickHouse%20does%20not%20support%20dependent,engine%20table%20for%20the%20update.) that uses [join table engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/join/). However, join table data is stored in memory and I have memory resitrictions. How can I achieve the same result by not creating a in-memory table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic in this realm. And the spoon does exists.

You can use that approach with samples and make many updates. Piece by piece by 10% for example.

Comment: I need one clarification, Won't I have to keep the temp join table in memory and wait until **optimize table final**  is finished. Otherwise, if I drop the temporary join table before the actual update is done, and create a new one to get from the next sample (i.e. next 10%) when the mutation runs in the background, it will fetch from this new temporary join table.

Comment: You need to wait until alter is finished. Then move to next 10%. Check `select from system.mutations where not is done`