# How can i update clickhouse data with subquery?

Tags: sql-update, clickhouse

In SQL, it is allowed to make an update by a subquery from another table.
Now, i can't find somethind like this in Yandex Clickhouse.
I know about https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/update/, but i want smth like:

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import
SET
    Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM
    Sales_Import SI
INNER JOIN
    RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
ON 
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID;
```

any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764093/updating-rows-with-values-from-another-table-in-clickhouse/55775479#55775479

Comment: thanks a lot. It's look helpful